# How to reformat CSV file?

Tags: c#, csv

I need to change the format of my CSV file.

My CSV file :

```
x,a,b,c
e,,2,1
f,3,15,
g,7,8,9
```

Needed format:

```
ea0
eb2
ec1
fa3
fb15
fc0
ga7
gb8
gc9
```

I've written code but it's not working:

```
string log = retval(textBox1.Text, 0, 512);
string[,] head = new string[4, 4];

int row=0;
int column=0;

string[] lines = log.Split('\n');
foreach (string l in lines)
{
    string[] split = l.Split(',');
    foreach (string item in split)
    {

        head[row, column] = item;
        column++;
    }
    row++;
}


for (row=1; row < 4; row++)
{
    string tmp = "";
    for (column = 1; column < 4; column++)
    {
        tmp = head[row, column];

    }
    listBox1.Items.Add(tmp);
}
```

Comment: logic behind this format is not clear.Why you want this format and how you are creating this format manually.

Comment: Are you wanting the "ea0", "eb2" values to end up in `listBox1`?

Comment: I'm adding a clarification edit for him. Please be patient. I've cracked the code! :)

Comment: Why is it not working? Have you stepped in the code using the Debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are going for here, but how about this:

```
foreach (string l in lines)
{
    string[] split = l.Trim().Split(',');
    foreach (string item in split)
    {

        head[row, column] = item;
        column++;
    }
    row++;
    column = 0;
}

for (row = 1; row < 4; row++)
{
    for (column = 1; column < 4; column++)
    {
        string rowAndColumn = head[row, 0] + head[0, column];
        string value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(head[row, column]) ? "0" : head[row, column];

        listBox1.Items.Add(rowAndColumn + value);
    }
}
```

An important change is the `column = 0;` in the first `foreach` loop. Without this, your `column` index will always end up being out of bounds.

The second `foreach` loop retrieves the row and column value and concatenates it with the numeric value. Doing this, I get the desired output given your input.

Comment: it's working good but in fc0 this returned fc
please correct it
thanks

Comment: @HadiRanji It works fine for me, but see my edit. In this case I have switched the line `string[] split = l.Split(',');` to `string[] split = l.Trim().Split(',');`. Doing this should prevent problems where a line ends in blank space.

Comment: @HadiRanji It's the second line of code in my answer. The change is that `l` is now trimmed of whitespace before splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the index at 1 instead of 0 ,

use this instead :

```
    for (row=0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        string tmp = "";
        for (column = 0; column < 4; column++)
        {
            tmp = head[row, column];

        }
        listBox1.Items.Add(tmp);
    }
```